# Problem when embedding a Flutter app into Rails html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flutter

I want to display a specific link of my flutter web app with flutter.js and the hostElement engine initialization parameter.

**Note:**
Domain server Flutter apps are different from Rails web.

**Expectation:**
Fully load an page with embeded Flutter

**Problem:**
Return a blank page with some errors related with History, which I'm not sure if it is the cause
`SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://example.com/demo' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:3000' and URL 'http://localhost:3000/demo'`

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= display_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <base href="https://example.com/">
    <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
        // Download main.dart.js
        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          onEntrypointLoaded: async function(engineInitializer) {
            // Initialize the Flutter engine
            let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
            // Run the app
            await appRunner.runApp();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did try this approaching https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/125330#issuecomment-1520946370. But it doesn't work either.